# Load balancing of network requests between replicas of services in docker swarm mode

Tags: node.js, docker, load-balancing, swarm

I cannot find any docs on used algorithm of load balancing between replicas of a service of docker in swarm mode.

I created an image `mynodeapp` based from the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest                                                                                                                                                                        
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                               
WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                    
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/                                                                                                                                                         
RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                         
COPY . /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                     
EXPOSE 8080                                                                                                                                                                             
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`npm` starts the following `server.js`:

```
const LATENCY = 5000;
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
        console.log('Sending response');
        setTimeout( function() {
                res.send('All ok');
        }, LATENCY );
});
app.listen( 8080 );
```

The code just sends `All ok` after 5-secs delay. Also, it prints `Sending response` to console.

Now, I start the docker swarm mode:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr:eth0
```

and start service with two replicas:

```
docker service create mynodeapp --replicas 2 --publish 8080:8080
```

The result is

```
root@man1:~# docker service ls
ID            NAME             REPLICAS  IMAGE      COMMAND
233z44bz6sx0  amazing_hypatia  2/2       mynodeapp  



root@man1:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        PORTS               NAMES
1f36e0c9eb37        8080/tcp         amazing_hypatia.1.453u2upnyf2nvtwxouopv4olk

f0fb099a5154        8080/tcp            amazing_hypatia.2.8lbs461uhiv2qvh28433ayi0g
```

Now, i open two terminals and look on the logs of both containers:

```
 docker logs amazing_hypatia.2.8lbs461uhiv2qvh28433ayi0g -f
```

and

```
docker logs  amazing_hypatia.2.8lbs461uhiv2qvh28433ayi0g -f
```

When I run

```
curl localhost:8080
```

I get `Sending response` one time from one terminal  and another time from another terminal. So it **seems like round-robin** load balancing is used.

But what is real load-balancing algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is currently a simple round-robin. There have been suggestions to enable a fastest expected response time algorithm that would solve the problem of requests getting routed to another docker host with the service is also running locally, but this has not been implemented yet.

---

From [docker's swarm networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/):

> The swarm load balancer automatically routes the HTTP request to the
>   service’s VIP to an active task. It distributes subsequent requests to
>   other tasks using round-robin selection.

The comments about using fastest expected response are from some dockercon 2016 videos that I can't pull up right now.

Comment: Can you provide some link(s) supporting your answer? I just cannot find any source discussing this issue.

Comment: Updated with a link and quote from dockers documentation on this.